# How to handle form closing events

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am using Windows Forms in c# and have problems with how and when the the different forms (i have 2) should close and not. It is very annoying since i feel that i should be able to fix it. But here we go.

I have two forms, one MainForm that calls another form called ContactForm.

The MainForm:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContactForm frmContact = new ContactForm();
        int index = lstCustomers.SelectedIndex;
        //If a customer is selected, export data for the selected customer to ContactForm
        if (index != -1)
        {
            frmContact.ContactData = customerMngr.GetCustomer(index).ContactData;
        }

        if (frmContact.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //Show the ContactForm object
        {
            //The user has chosen the OK button - add the new customer object
            customerMngr.AddCustomer(frmContact.ContactData);   //??      
            UpdateCustomerList();
        }

        if (frmContact.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

And the form that is called:
OK button.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidateInput())
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Cancel button:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to cancel and discard all data?", "Cancel input", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

When the OK button in the ContactForm is used i want it to close, which works. When i press the cancel button, and no (in the box that appears), i want the form to stay open with the input still intact. Right now it doesn´t work.

Any ideas?

/Martin

Comment: If you did it right then the DialogResult is already set when the buttons' Click event starts running.  So if it is canceled then you have to set the DialogResult back to None.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I should have seen that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is alright. I think the problem lies in your `Cancel Button` itself. By this I mean that you probably attached (by designer or somewhere in code) `DialogResul.Cancel` to your button `btnCancel.DialogResul` property. To fix this simply set it to `DialogResult.None`.

If I'm right this is what is closing your second form.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Oh you are good. I had put DialogResult to Cancel when designing the form. I did it because my teacher explicitly told me to. Oh well, what does he know :P Thanks once again!